# Light theme for AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I'm creating an AlertDialog. I'm using setView() to set a custom view. This enables the 'dark' theme on the dialog (grey background, and need white text).

Is there a way to set the dialog to use the 'light' theme? It looks nicer (white background, dark text).

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Answer (score 4):

Steps I took:

- Create a class extending Dialog.
- In the onCreate, call
  setContentView(x, y) with x being
  your R.layout and y being
  R.style.popupStyle (see below).
- In your res/values/style.xml, you
  need to override the default
  DialogWindow style. I tried just
  making a style that has this one as
  its parent, but that still didn't
  clear all defaults. So I checked the
  Android git tree and got the default
  style, and just copy-pasted it. This
  is the one

:

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/panel_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

You'll get a few errors, just solve them by copying more stuff from the official Android styles.xml and themes.xml files.

for reference: [styles.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;hb=HEAD) and [themes.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;hb=HEAD).

Comment: DialogWindowTitle don't public, should use: ?android:attr/windowTitleStyle

Comment: This leaves a white border around the actual dialog, so far I found no way to remove the border to be transparent so the dialog shadow is actually rendered to the real background and not on a white border