# Set a background to buttons in a dialog?

Tags: android, xml

I have a dialog, which works just fine for me, but I want to set my background for two buttons in this dialog. The structure of it is quite complicated so I don't want to rewrite it to a custom dialog. But in this case, is there any possibility to set a background(more specifically, is there a way to set a style to positive/negative/neutral buttons)?

Comment: You mean u Want to change the Default Colour from the custom Colour for the Dialog box ???

Comment: What?... I have a dialog like this: http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/8502/dialogx.png and I want these gray buttons be like this http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/glossy_buttons/glossy_button_blank_blue_oval.png. I have a special .xml in drawables, which I assign through the "background" tag to buttons.

Comment: Look into this [Android Dialog with custom Color and Design](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30388711/782535).

Comment: look at this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520967/how-to-change-the-colour-of-positive-and-negative-button-in-custom-alert-dialog

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fundamentally you want to access the dialog buttons: these (on the standard AlertDialog) currently have ids `android.R.id.button1` for positive, `android.R.id.button2` for negative, and `android.R.id.button3` for neutral.

So for example to set the background image on the neutral button you can do this:

```
Dialog d;
//
// create your dialog into the variable d
//
((Button)d.findViewById(android.R.id.button3)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_background);
```

EDIT: this is if you are using an AlertDialog.Builder to create it. For all I know these button assignments may change in the future, so keep that in mind.

EDIT: The chunk of code below should generate something that looks like what you want. It turns out you have to call show BEFORE you change the background

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("TEST MESSAGE)
        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
((Button)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button1)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);
```

Comment: It says "Multiple markers at this line
 - Button cannot be resolved to a type
 - Button cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type 
  AlertDialog.Builder". I have `AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity1.MY);
  alert.setTitle(R.string.exclude_title);`. Then `alert.setPositiveButton("Delete",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      // TODO
     }
});

((Button)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.button1)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_border);`

Comment: You need `AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity1.MY); alert.setTitle(R.string.exclude_title);` then `alert.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // TODO } });`. Then `Dialog d = alert.create();`. Then `((Button)d.findViewById(android.R.id.button1)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawa­ble.button_border);`;

Comment: I don't get errors now, but the dialog left the same. I tried to set different values, - no effect.

Comment: Pleeeeaaase, somebody help me!

Comment: Iomza, can you edit your question with a complete chunk of code, including the section where you actually show the dialog? If the dialog doesn't change I suspect the specific instance you are displaying is not the same one you modified.

Comment: @Femi, thank you so much! I also set the text appearance(same way as with background) =) But it's kinda odd to me, why changes should be made after calling the show() method...

Comment: All good. I'm guessing it doesn't inflate the views until you call `show()` so there's nothing to update: On my test device it threw a null pointer exception if I tried to alter the background before calling `show()`;

Comment: I think the answer here to the similiar problem is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8077918/1016462

Comment: Button b = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE); In this way we can get the button from alert dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's a better and more reliable way to get the buttons for the `Dialog` than the one posted by @Femi .

You can use the [getButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton%28int%29) method:

```
Button positiveButton = yourDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
```

The [DialogInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html#BUTTON_POSITIVE) provides all the needed constants:

```
DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL
DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the standard text buttons and change the background of the buttons and the whole dialog you can define your own dialog theme in `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

...and then when you build the dialog to set its background like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me note that this would be bad practice to override the show() method for such problem.

In order to encapsulate the solution into the creation of the dialog itself, best practice is to have the buttons customization within dialog constructor:

```
class CustomDialog extends AlertDialog
{
    public CustomDialog(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                Button negativeButton = getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);  
                Button positiveButton = getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

                negativeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                positiveButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
Button bn = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
bn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
Button bp = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
bp.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  Has no effect on color.  I used Color.BLUE btw.