# How to change the colour of Positive and negative button in Custom Alert dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

**What i am doing:** I am creating a custom alert dialog

**What i am trying to do:** along with below code, How to change the color of action buttons in dialog(positive and negative)

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // sign in the user ...
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
               }
           });      
    return builder.create();
```

Comment: Check this link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439538/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-alertdialog-title-and-the-color-of-the-line-under)

Answer (score 42):

you can do it like this-

```
public void createDialog(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit from app");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You exit from app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    nbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it via styles or themes? Doing this for many or every dialog does not seem like a good idea

Comment: yes,Why not. you can do it by styles also. try this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/24560017/3912847

Comment: I don't see how that link solves the problem, which styles would refer to the positive button style and which to the negative button. I only see `android:borderlessButtonStyle`

Comment: You can make a utility method for creating AlertDialog. Every time you need a dialog, use that utility method. No code duplication.

Comment: Perfect! Helped me

Comment: Do we have to the the `getButton` after the `alert.show()`? Is it possible to do it befor ethe `alert.show()`?

Answer (score 16):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.DialogeTheme);
```

---

```
<style name="DialogeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/all_item_bg</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This paints the whole dialog

Answer (score 10):

you can overwrite onStart method to get handle of all the buttons (Positive, Negative and Neutral).

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View eventEditDialogView = View.inflate(this.getActivity(), R.layout.event_edit_dialog,
                                            null);

    builder.setTitle(getLocalizedString("edit_event"))
            .setView(eventEditDialogView)
            .setPositiveButton(getLocalizedString("all_events"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getLocalizedString("this_event"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            })
    return builder.create();
}

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    Button positive = ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    positive.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    positive.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GrayBGColor));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//***The simpliest solution is:***

dialog.show(); //Only after .show() was called
dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(neededColor);
dialog.getButton(dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(neededColor);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **setOnShowListener** method of the AlertDialog to get the buttons and apply a different color and their own listeners, here you have an example in Kotlin:

```
val alert : AlertDialog?
val alertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert_add_product, null, false)

val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setCancelable(false)
    builder.setView(alertView)

    /**Create positive and negative buttons**/
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)

    alert = builder.create()

    /**Listener called when the AlertDialog is shown**/
    alert.setOnShowListener {

         /**Get the positive button from the AlertDialog**/
         val positiveButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

         /**Set your color to the positive button**/
         positiveButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bluePrimaryDark))

         /**Set listener to the positive button**/
         positiveButton.setOnClickListener({
              alert.dismiss()
         })

         /**Get the negative button from the AlertDialog**/
         val negativeButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)

         /**Set your color to the negative button**/
         negativeButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bluePrimaryDark))

         /**Set listener to the negative button**/
         negativeButton.setOnClickListener {
              alert?.dismiss()
         }
    }

    alert.show()
```