# Custom AlertDialog style Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles

How to make custom style for example for green buttons and background of message using AlertDialog. ???

Definition of AlertDialog:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(About.this, R.style.MY_AlertDialog);
```

And style:

```
<style name="MY.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Try this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/27521470/3912847 .If you want to customize the layout then you have to inflate the xml

Comment: thx, what about changing background in message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-the-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without using custom style or inflating the custom view like below code.

```
public void createDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit from app");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewPagerStyle1Activity.this,
                    "You exit from app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    TextView messageText = (TextView) alert
            .findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    nbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```