# Android Custom Alert Dialog Error after updating android sdk r12

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I got the following error after updating my android sdk revision to r12.

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/AlertDialog'.
```

**Here is my xml file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/AlertDialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Theme.Dialog</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I didn't change anything in the code and the only thing that I did was upgraded the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found the answer . i know its not the proper way but it works for now.

```
I managed to fix it by replacing the platform-tools_r06 with platform-
tools_r05 in android sdk folder
```

you can dowload platform-tools-r05 from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r05-windows.zip).

Answer (score 0):

`android:style/AlertDialog` is not a public style and you should not use it. Please refer to this thread [How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Comment: ... But then in the comments below they say use `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` which actually works.