# How to reduce AlertDialog.Builder title font size and positive button size?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to reduce the `AlertDialog.Builder` title font size and positive button size? If yes, Just let me how to do?

Comment: you might want to check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About font size you can use this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilser = new SpannableStringBuilder("Sample");
StyleSpan span = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
ScaleXSpan span1 = new ScaleXSpan(1);
ssBuilser.setSpan(span, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
ssBuilser.setSpan(span1, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

builder.setTitle(ssBuilser);

builder.show();
```

Also You can set custom title:

```
float size = 25;    

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
final TextView myView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
myView.setText("A Sample Title to Change Dialog Title");
myView.setTextSize(size);
builder.setCustomTitle(myView);
```

Comment: it is not working for me.i need text size like 12dp or 14dp.can u tell me how can i do this

Comment: I've updated my post, You can try it. You can use display metrics to get size in dp. For example: 14 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

Answer (score 3):

Yo can create youtr own dialog so you can set the layout as you want:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(act,R.style.MyTheme);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setOwnerActivity(act);
    //In the layout XML you can set the text size or the button size. 
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    //you can set your text size here
    text.setTextSize(mySize);
    text.setText("my text"); 


    Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    //you can change the button dimensions here
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //actions
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Regards.