# Display an image over an app in this way

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to display an image preview over my app: when user presses an item in the listview (each item is a path to an image stored in sd card) image preview appears,stretched in the available space, like in this picture (image space is black, underlying app, still partially visible, is gray):

[image]

when user presses back image disappear.
I thought to make an activity just for image displaying but I don't know how to obtain the result in the picture...

Edit:

Ok here's what I've done so far:

1)Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ImageDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
 </activity>
```

2)Layout:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

3)Activity onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.image_preview);
String filepath = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_filepath");  
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageBitmap(getBitmap(filepath));
```

where getBitmap is a private method which gives me a bitmap from a filepath.

Problem is that I don't have control over dialog dimensions: dialog's width and height seem to depend on contained image ones...not to mention top/right/left/bottom margins...

**Solved (maybe):
I modified layout file this way:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

>

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Setting width/height to a square allowed to obtain the effect...my question is: will it work for every phone?Or it is right just for mine?

Comment: check api demos -- in v2.2 activitl like dialog i think it will help

Comment: Can I have a link?I did something with theme=dialog, but resulting dialog is too small

Comment: Maybe because its doesn't have content...

Comment: Of curse it has, problem is that, even if I set layout width/heigth to fill parent the dialog is very small!!

Comment: of course dialog has default width and height try using the below code you can set height and width for that

Comment: What code?Anyway I updated post with mine...maybe you can help me finding what I'm getting wrong

Comment: Maybe the dialog was too small because your image is too small. Try to add a bigger one and set both its layout parameters to "fill_parent".

Answer (score 1):

Your best shot is to display your image in a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

If you then want more control over the display, [theme it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this by creating a new `Activity`, you should set its layout parameters to `wrap_content` so it will appears above the other activity but not fitting the screen totally. Also by setting its theme as `Theme.Dialog` or an inherited theme, you 2nd activity will be a little bit darker and your activity will appear like a dialog.

You should also try to put layout parameter to `fill_parent` and add margins if you want the exact result as you shown (don't know if this solution could work).

Answer (score 0):

this is from api demos creating an activit like a dilog try this

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Initialization of the Activity after it is first created.  Must at least
 * call {@link android.app.Activity#setContentView setContentView()} to
 * describe what is to be displayed in the screen.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Be sure to call the super class.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);

    // See assets/res/any/layout/dialog_activity.xml for this
    // view layout definition, which is being set here as
    // the content of our screen.
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_activity);

    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work...I even get an alert icon on activity title so I guess it's not even a good practice :(

Comment: you are only setting that icon    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, 
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
you avoid that there wont be an icon (pls read the code and try to understand what s going on)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, solution entered in main post seems working fine!