# Trigger IO Android Theming

Tags: android, trigger.io

Is there a way to activiate holo theme for native menus (in my case, a "ContextMenu" hacked out of an AlertDialog) in a trigger android app?

Comment: I would think there would be a way, but I've not tried so I'm not sure how, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog might be of help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I linked to in my comment turned out to work.

A quick example of how to use this in a plugin:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(ForgeApp.getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo));
dialog.setTitle("Hello");
dialog.show();
```