# How to open system dialog box for entering password for a secured wifi network in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am struggling around with achieving the dialog box which appears when a secured wifi network is discovered . I am attaching the image of that dialog box . I simply want to invoke such dialog box from my application.

[image: As seen in this image how to open such dialog box using intent or there is any other way to do it?]

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is not as clear as it could be, there are 2 possible answers

1) If you want to create a dialog looking like the one in the picture, try styling an AlertDialog. It should not be too hard to do it. For examples, take a look at this questions: [How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

2) If you want to open the system dialog box for entering the password for a Wi-Fi, I have some bad news. That functionality is not available via Intents or other means of IPC. The best you could do is direct the user towards the Wi-Fi settings page using this Activity invocation:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Hope this answers your question.