# Wrong style of AlertDialog with setSingleChoiceItems after setTheme()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I'm changing application theme with this code:

MainActivity.java:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppBlackTheme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
<style name="AppBlackTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black" />
```

And then creating AlertDialog:

```
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.templates_list_item, new String[] {"name","descr"}, new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.descr});
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setSingleChoiceItems(simpleAdapter, -1, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //...
            }
        });
alert.show();
```

But in Android 2.1 this AlertDialog displaying with white background and white text. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try: `setInverseBackgroundForced(true)`

Comment: Sorry, but this is doesn't help (nothing changed).

Answer (score 1):

You are using default Android Theme. This means the OS will decide the colors. If you set colors yourself it can happen you are getting in the way of the standard theme.

Try to customize or use you're own defined Theme. see the following topic for more information.

[How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Comment: I've try this, but it doesn't help... android:textColor doesn't change text of Alert's ListView items.

Comment: Did you changed the R.layout.templates_list_item? What color is the text there?

Comment: No, I didn't change it. But how to change it? R.layout.templates_list_item doesn't have any color directive:

...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
...

Comment: use android:textColor="@color/text_color" for the textview

Comment: I add answer with my solution... I hope that is correct and my understanding is right. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Now I do that:

values/styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="alert_text_color">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppBlackTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
        <item name="alert_text_color">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <item name="alert_text_color">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppBlackTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" >
        <item name="alert_text_color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="customAttrs">
        <attr name="alert_text_color" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and in layout (templates_list_item):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="?attr/alert_text_color" />
```