# Android prevent activity style from being applied to alertdialogs

Tags: android, styles, android-alertdialog

I have some little customization in my style.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_grey</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Now the styling is correctly applied to my activities.

But when I create an alertdialog, the background color is applied to the title and body of the dialog, which I do not want. I want the alertdialog to remain to its stock styling.

Here is the alertdialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Wtitle").setMessage("message");
            builder.setNeutralButton("ok", null);
            builder.show();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have You applied AppBaseTheme to app, not activities?

Answer (score 0):

There's working solution - use another `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor with theme as described in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29), idea is basically come from this ["How to change theme for AlertDialog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog):

- There's one weird thing in your styles.xml: app theme defines `android:background` instead of `android:windowBackground`. Seems there's no reason to do so, because if You need same background for *all* views (which I doubt is possible) then You can have some base theme for views. I think, interfering application theme and views themes is basically not a good idea, because app needs completely different attributes. So, let's make it the following:

  ```
  <resources>
      <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

      <!-- Application theme. -->
      <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
          <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_grey</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
      </style>
  </resources>
  ```
- Dialog Builder should be created with it's own theme:

  ```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
  ```

  Here please note that by some reason, constructor [AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) doesn't do it right and `ContextThemeWrapper` is necessary (seems it's because not all properties are in the theme and theme gets 'recreated' only using ContextThemeWrapper).