# How to avoid dialog using same style with activity?

Tags: android, dialog, styles

i'm using custom style for my activity, it's affect the dialog (alertdialog, DatePickerDialog, etc) using that style too. how can i avoid alertdialog to not using the same style with activity ??

this is the code in style.xml :

```
    <style name="Custom.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cag_white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cag_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Cag.Dialog.TextView</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Cag.EditText</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Cag.Button</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the theme for your dialog the way you want it. Check the examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog) or [here](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/05/09/theme-android-dialog/).

However, I personally prefer to use `DialogFragments` and set the styling myself through `onCreateView`.

Comment: great , this link > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog
work for me . thanks @gunar . :)