# Changing the highlighting colors (button colors) of a "DialogPreference"

Tags: android, styles, themes

I implemented a **DialogPreference** exactly the way it is explained in http://www.lukehorvat.com/blog/android-seekbardialogpreference

Additionally I was able to change the text- and divider color of the **DialogPreference**, but I couldn't change the highlighting color of the buttons when they are pressed. Does anybody know how to do this?

**Update:**

I use the following layout for the **DialogPreference**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dialog_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
        android:paddingRight="12dip"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The only style attributes regarding this **DialogPreference** or the layout I change so far are changed programatically:

```
        int alertTitleId = this.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
        TextView alertTitle = (TextView) getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(alertTitleId);
        alertTitle.setTextColor(color); // change title text color

        int titleDividerId = this.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
        View titleDivider = getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
        titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(color); // change divider color
```

Comment: Your Layout is Custom or Default

Comment: have a look at the latest update :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is subclass `DialogPreference`, then call `Resource.getIdentifier` to locate each `View` you want to theme, much like you're doing, but you don't need to call `Window.getDecorView`. Here's an example:

**Custom `DialogPreference`**

```
public class CustomDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {

    public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);
        final Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        final int green = res.getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);

        // Title
        final int titleId = res.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
        final View title = window.findViewById(titleId);
        if (title != null) {
            ((TextView) title).setTextColor(green);
        }

        // Title divider
        final int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
        final View titleDivider = window.findViewById(titleDividerId);
        if (titleDivider != null) {
            titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(green);
        }

        // Button views
        window.findViewById(res.getIdentifier("button1", "id", "android"))
                .setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_selector));
        window.findViewById(res.getIdentifier("button2", "id", "android"))
                .setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_selector));
        window.findViewById(res.getIdentifier("button3", "id", "android"))
                .setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_selector));

    }

}
```

**XML preferences**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <path_to.CustomDialogPreference
        android:dialogMessage="Message"
        android:negativeButtonText="Cancel"
        android:positiveButtonText="Okay"
        android:title="Title" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Custom selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:autoMirrored="true">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_pressed_drawable" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_default_drawable"/>

</selector>
```

**Alternate selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:autoMirrored="true">

    <item android:drawable="@color/your_pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/your_default_color/>

</selector>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid it's not the answer I am looking for. I'd like to change the color of the button the moment it is pressed :)

Comment: Yeah, exactly. My example doesn't include a `selector`, but that's all you need. Then just call `View.setBackgroundDrawable`. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you fail to find a solution for styling the built-in buttons to your liking, you could actually add a button row to the bottom of your custom layout, which looks and acts exactly like the built-in one.  Then set your button listeners to your custom button bar's buttons, which will result in no built-in button bar.

In this way you can make them look however you want!

Answer (score 0):

I you can try [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870997/1315117). Here you don't need write code just need customise AlertDialog theme.

After customisation theme it may be applicable for your complete application.