# ID of top divider in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm using the following code to theme my AlertDialogs.

```
Resources resources = dialog.getContext().getResources();
int color = resources.getColor(R.color.green_theme); // your color here

int alertTitleId = resources.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
TextView alertTitle = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(alertTitleId);
alertTitle.setTextColor(color); // change title text color

int titleDividerId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
View titleDivider = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerId);
titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(color); // change divider color
```

It works well, except for the case where I have an AlertDialog with a message but no title. It appears that there is a third View that is only displayed in this case, which also needs to have its color set. I just don't know what the id of this View is. Does anyone know it?

The View I'm talking about is highlighted in the white rectangle in the picture below.

[image: AlertDialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that no one actually read my question.

Anyways, here's the answer if anyone else has his issue:

```
int titleDividerTopId = resources.getIdentifier("titleDividerTop", "id", "android");
View titleDividerTop = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(titleDividerTopId);
titleDividerTop.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

That should get rid of the title.

Comment: I don't want to get rid of it, I want to change the color so that it matches the text.

Comment: AFAIK, thats part of the theme you're using. You'll have to adjust the theme. Here's a SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing just change the theme of your whole application as transparent in your manifest file's `application` tag as below:

Which will not show your blue line in your dialog.

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
```