# Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

### What I am doing:

- I am using this in activity
- My activity extends  ActionBarActivity
- My minimum sdk is 8 in manifest

### I am getting the error as:

```
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder
```

---

### CODE

```
public void openSettings(String custMsg){

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
        alert.setMessage(custMsg);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                tryAgainId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                locationValidationDone=true;
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }
```

---

### Question:

How can i resolve this

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder(context,theme)` is added in API level 11 but min sdk is 8. to avoid this error use `AlertDialog.Builder(context)` or @NewApi before method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K ......... Yes that fixes ! ... so if i need to use a custom style for a dialog as i have done ... only waay s to use higher API's ?

Comment: @Devrath : see [How to change theme for AlertDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog) post to set custom theme before api level 11

Comment: @Devrath Are you going to choose an answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context,%20int)):

**The constructor you are using requires API 11.**

```
public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int theme)

Added in API level 11
Constructor using a context and theme for this builder and the AlertDialog it creates. The actual theme that an AlertDialog uses is a private implementation, however you can here supply either the name of an attribute in the theme from which to get the dialog's style (such as alertDialogTheme or one of the constants AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK, or AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT.
```

**You need to use the contructor added in API 1:**

```
public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context)

Added in API level 1
Constructor using a context for this builder and the AlertDialog it creates.
```

Comment: Who downvoted this answer? This is straight from the `android docs`.

Comment: Its true, but it is better to give a comprehensive solution

Comment: @ImanMarashi What are you talking about? I showed both the old and new apis. I even provided the docs. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

With this method to permanently fix that:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static void showAlert(int paramInt, String title, Activity act,
        String message) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act,
                R.style.CustomDialog);
        TextView messageText = new TextView(act);
        messageText.setText(message);
        localBuilder.setTitle(title);
        messageText
                .setTextColor(act.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        messageText.setTextSize(18);
        messageText.setLineSpacing(1f, 1.5f);
        localBuilder.setView(messageText);
        localBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        messageText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        AlertDialog dialog = localBuilder.show();
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(act);
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        TextView messageText = new TextView(act);
        messageText.setText(message);
        dialog.setContentView(messageText);
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

and `CustomDialog` style:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use constructor

```
public AlertDialog.Builder(Context)
```

instead of

```
public AlertDialog.Builder(Context, int)
```

Declare theme of dialog in `styles.xml`.