# Custom dialog with custom shape and working buttons

Tags: java, android, dialog

I need to create a dialog which displays text:"Choose your gamemode" and then when user clicks on specific button (4 buttons total), execute the action with onItemClickListener(). But I want from it to have the custom shape. Here is my code for the shape:

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

<corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="80dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="80dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="80dp"
        android:topRightRadius="80dp" />
```

How should I continue with defining the layout and how can I make the dialog itself ?

EDIT:

Now the code works but I can see the ugly black rectangular borders around my DialogActivity. How can I remove them ?

Comment: To make your dialog: [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). To style, what about [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)?

Comment: that's not exactly what I wanted. I wanted to have a dialog, not AlertDialog. And I don't know either how to make the layout for it.

Comment: You can make your custom `Activity`. Make the background transparent except for your "dialog window"

Comment: Thanks for that. And now the most important thing, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments:
[This](http://www.javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/) can be handy for you.

Comment: You can make your own theme based on the code you wrote above. For example (in the `res/values/` folder of your project): 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       <!-- your code -->
    </style>
</resources>`
Then just set your style in the activity xml:
`<activity
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name="DialogActivityDemoActivity"
 android:theme="@android:style/mytheme" > </activity>`

Comment: well, the code works, butI cant make my theme because it won't accept the 'shape'

Comment: How can I remove that ugly black rectangle that's displaying as additional background around my custom shape ?