# How to customize the progress dialog Android

Tags: android

I want to recreate a `Progress Dialog` similar to the first one (top-left) of the image:

[image]

But how can I possibly customize it in order to have that kind of background?

Comment: Customized `Progress Dialog` with `Android` style. Not `iOS`

Comment: @MD What does it mean? sorry I didn't understand

Answer (score 1):

You should read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897269/4170584) on SO. It will show you how to use styles.xml to customize dialog.

If you not familiar with styles and themes you can read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html) or this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).