# Status bar colour not able to set when dialog is shown in android

Tags: android

I use Theme ***android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar***

```
 private void popupControl() {
    final AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_control);
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.relative_dialog_control).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_close_top).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

in androidMainfest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

this is style

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_bg_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
```

[image]

When I show dialog. StatusBar colour not working. Please. Help me?

[image]

Comment: Not working means, are you getting any error or you are not able to see color of your choice in status bar?

Comment: I am not able to see color of my choice in status bar?

Comment: I remove android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar. StatusBar colour worked. But I must use android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar give my application.

Comment: I update my picture.

Comment: check this, hope this will help you to resolved your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Comment: I have same Problem , you got the solution ?