# Android. PreferenceActivity. ListPreference. How can I change the backgrounds color of ListPreference?

Tags: android, background, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

Implements the "night theme". I don't know how to change the background color of ListPreference.

[PreferenceActivity "day" theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ZII.png)

[PreferenceActivity night theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne9Zl.png)

As you can see, only to pick up the color of the title of "night" colors.

I use the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_window</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/SettingsFragmentStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/icons</item>
</style>

<style name="SettingsFragmentStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_window</item>
</style>
```

What parameters are responsible for:

1. Backgrounds ListPreference;
2. Text color ListPreference items;
3. Color "switches" ListPreference - I want to replace on the "accent" color (orange in my case).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a style for your Dialog.

**The dialog style**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="android:colorBackground">#1E1E1E</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#D8D8D8</item>
<item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">#D8D8D8</item>
<item name="color">#80CBC4</item>
```

then set the dialog style in your main style

```
<style name="AppNight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

**AppNight** is my Night theme I didn't mention the other attributes of my theme to minimize the code.

[image: see here how it looks]

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code below to your dark theme in the styles.xml. It also changes the way the dialog is displayed, so it'll be it's own page instead of the card style.

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rhl5.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1388R.png)

Otherwise I you have to make a custom alert dialog, Try this [How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)