# Alert Dialog background theme/Color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to set `AlertDialogue` theme or *change* background color.

Though I know it has a default theme but in different version I am getting different theme so I want to fix it for all version.

Or simply change background color as white

```
 @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), imagesWithNames, R.layout.lib_dialog_image,
                new String[]{"name", "imageID","Spacing"}, new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.image1,R.id.spacing});
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setAdapter(adapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ((PlaceCallActivity) getContext()).OnSelected(WithNamesFragment.this.getClass(), (int) ((HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i)).get("imageID"));
                    }
                }).setCancelable(true).setTitle("PICK YOUR AVATAR").setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create();
    }
```

Don't post your code please tell where I should make a change here.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
```

**Note :** The Above line would do it but I want to know where I should give style for my `AlertDialogue`

[image]

Comment: In your values/styles.xml you create a new style named "AlertDialogCustom"

Comment: are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Yes I haven't found one yet!

Comment: Refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create your style in your `styles.xml` file as follows.

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:headerDividersEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

Then Create `Alert Dialog` using Builder as follows

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this/getActvity(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
```

Here passing the current class Context and style to the `ContextThemeWrapper` class constructor.

Comment: First look and tell me what I should do there I cant add this to my return dialog not able to Ankit Shah is doing it right but there is some problem

Comment: @SamH67 tell me exactly what do you want. Then I can help you.

Comment: I want to do it my way because I am not able to add your code. Look at my code and tell me how to add but please try  before doing it  because I have already tried this thing before I have posted this question so I already know this thing but I am able to change theme inside that return statement

Comment: See my **note** Saurabh you have posted same thing I already told you I know this thing still you have posted same line in answer.

Comment: No it couldn't shouldn't work it says cannot resolve constructor context theme wrapper

Comment: And now dont say I have not created style for this, Please if you have a solution then post else dont vote me down for no reason OK?

Comment: OK but here it isn't working you can see the image added by me. Maybe something else I have to try. If you have another way of doing it let me know ok?

Comment: I have a class public class WithNamesFragment extends DialogFragment

Comment: in the place of 'this' use `getActivity().getApplicationContext();`  or `getContext()` to pass the context.

Comment: Now setAdapter is getting red underline it says cannot resolve method setAdapter

Comment: Got it sorry I was missing bracket this getContext() this worked now it look like this (new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom)) last bracket was missing now It's ok let me run and then I'll verify your answer ok

Comment: Can I reduce the header size of a dialog?

Comment: Tell me in short how to do it.

Comment: @MML that is your activity context

Answer (score 5):

You should add dialog style inside res/values/styles.xml. Like as below.

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Or you change background color as below also:

**EDIT:**

```
 getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.white);
```