# Android alert dialogue styling not working on samsung 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I have created style for android dialog in android & code is pasted below.But the styling does not seem to work on Android 6.0.1,samsung phone.I have sharing two screen shots as well.Please help me with this.

**Code**

```
<style name="GeneraButton1" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item><item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item><item name="android:textSize">@dimen/key_text</item><item name="android:gravity">center</item><item name="android:background">@drawable/general_button1_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons --><item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item><!-- Used for the title and text --><item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item><!-- Used for the title and text --><item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item><!-- Used for the background --><item name="android:background">@color/white</item><item name="android:button">@style/GeneraButton</item><item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/GeneraButton</item>
</style>
```

**JavaCode**

```
public void showAlertDialog(String title, String message, IAlertDialogueInterface handler, final View view, boolean setPositiveButton, int posBtnString, int negBtnStr) {
    final IAlertDialogueInterface internalHandler;
    if (handler == null) {
        internalHandler = new AlertHandler();
    } else {
        internalHandler = handler;
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    if (setPositiveButton) {
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(this.getString(posBtnString),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    internalHandler.onAlertButtonClick(arg1, view);
                }
            });
    }
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(this.getString(negBtnStr), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            internalHandler.onAlertButtonClick(which, view);
        }
    });

    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    if (view != null) {
        alertDialog.setView(view);
    }
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**MotoG4Plus (Android 7.0 screen shot)**[image]

**Samsung (Android 6.0.1 screen shot)**[image]

Comment: you have only one style.xml file? I mean you dont have na v23/styles.xml?

Comment: Please share the code where you tell your Alert Dialog to use that style. Try following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog

Comment: @David Have edited the code.Please check.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I have v21/styles but not v23/styles.

Comment: try add v23/styles with the same alert dialog styles and see if works

Comment: @BrunoFerreira it dint work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do if from code. Like below:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.YourAlertDialogStyle);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("title");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("message");
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    //2. now setup to change color of the button
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(
            new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
                // like this set text color to all your buttons in dialog
                alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(COLOR_YOU_WANT);
            }
    });
```

Happy coding !!!