# dialog background

Tags: java, android

ok, I am making an app for a phone.
I made a function for my dialog and just calling the function when needed.

I want to be able to change the dialog window ie: different colors and lines and stuff to separate the text out.

I have looked all over the internet and I cant find anything that can help me.

here is the function that I am calling....

```
public void userNameRequired(View view)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlerdDialog.Builder(this);
    TextView newMessage = new TextView(this);
    newMessage.setText(" User Name is Required to be between 7 and 20    caracters long.");
    newMesage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    builder.setView(newMessage);

    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("!! NOTICE !!");
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTextSize(28);
    title.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    builder.setCustomTitle(title);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {

        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: I have been looking on the internet for the last 2 days.

Comment: i want to be able to change the background  and add stuff like a line after the title and other stuff. can anyone help with this.

Comment: This function works but everything that i have tried in order to change the background  has failed.

Comment: I have tried.... this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.parseClolr("@0000ff")));, with many different variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by **pha**, you can assign a custom theme to the Alert Dialog :

[How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

1. Open `colors.xml`
2. Define color like this: `<color name="background_dark">#3F51B5</color>`
3. After calling `show()` on your dialog, set the background color like this:

   ```
   builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.background_dark);
   ```

**Solution 2:**

1. Define a custom theme

   ```
   //assuming you have `@color/White` and `@color/colorPrimaryDark` defined in `colors.xml`
   <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
       <item name="android:headerDividersEnabled">true</item>
       <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
       <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. set style

   ```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlerdDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
   ```

So, this is how your code should look like:

```
    public void userNameRequired(View view)
    {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlerdDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
       TextView newMessage = new TextView(this);
       newMessage.setText(" User Name is Required to be between 7 and 20    caracters long.");
       newMesage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
       builder.setView(newMessage);

       TextView title = new TextView(this);
       title.setText("!! NOTICE !!");
       title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
       title.setTextSize(28);
       title.setTextColor(Color.RED);

       builder.setCustomTitle(title);

       builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
       {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
           {

           }
       });

       builder.show();
    }

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyDialogTheme)
        ...
        .create();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, where do i add this new code. i have seen this type of code before in my search but i couldn't figure out where to add it.

Comment: i have tried to add it to my layout and a few different places but errors in all..

Comment: added more detail in Solution 1, please check and try

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. i am so dumb some times lol. i didn't even think of the styles.xml i was trying to figure out where to put the different styles lol

Comment: i have tried your first answer before adding this question. it didn't work. but trying second now

Comment: so i couldn't get it to work with the builder that i am using